# Angular4 : exclude list elements contained in an array

Tags: arrays, angular

I'm new to the Angular 4 and I'd like to exclude elements from a list is they are already contained in an array.

Let's say I have a `userItems` array. The user can add an item from a list, but in the current state of the project, in the case he chooses an item he already has, an error message is displayed.

A more simple and user friendly way to proceed would be to show only the elements he doesn't already have.

This is what I'm currently using :

```html
<option *ngFor="let userItem of userItems" value="{{ userItem.id }}">
   {{ userItem.name }}
</option>
```

How could I filter the results? I thought about using a pipe.

Comment: you can use loadash

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you could just watch the value of the input and conditionally remove that from the list.

You can assign the `option input` to a local variable within your view by using the `#input` syntax within the tag. And then from there you can apply the `*ngIf` directive to your menu items to compare them with the current value. And weed out the one that matches the current value.

For example:

```
<option #input *ngFor="let userItem of userItems" value="{{ userItem.id }}">
    <ng-container *ngIf="userItem.id !== input.value">
        {{ userItem.name }}
    </ng-container>
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use `ng-template`:

```
<option *ngFor="let userItem of userItems" value="{{ userItem.id }}">
  <ng-template [ngIf]="some-condition">
    {{ userItem.name }}
 </ng-template>
</option>
```

The alternative is to filter your array in your component using `filter` on the array when the user insert the new value.

```
userItems.filter(value => value !== 3);
```

I didn't completely understand your question maybe. If not Plese be more specific.